# Get files from custom folder inside C# project

Tags: c#, winforms, directory

First time poster (and newbie).

I've created a C# winform application.
I've added a "Documents" folder in which I've added 5 PDF files.

From within my Form1, I've added a button and inside the button click event, I'm trying to get the files from that "Documents" folder.

I've googled around and found stuff like this:

```
string[] arr = Directory.GetFiles(string path);
```

But I do not wish to "hardcode" the path of my "Documents" folder.
I'd like to know if there's a way (more dynamic) to obtain the path of my "Documents" folder.

I've also found these:

```
string path1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string path2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

But they always bring me to my \bin\Debug folder.

I'll take all the help I can get!
Thanks!

Comment: Can your `Documents` folder be anywhere or do you mean the "My Documents" folder in Windows?

Comment: My bad…I can understand the confusion!

My “Documents” folder is not the built-in windows “My Documents” folder…perhaps I should’ve named it something else to avoid confusion (now and later on).

I pretty much did Right-Click on the Project and selected Add-->New Folder and called it “Documents”

Comment: No problem, at least you got it solved :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration you mean?

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

<strike>Or am I misreading the question?</strike>

#### EDIT

I guess I did misread, my apologies. Try this:

```
string documents = Path.Combine(
                     Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath),
                     "Documents"
                   );
```

*This is also assuming you're including the items from the "documents" folder as resources so the executable will be able to see them.*

Comment: I think he added the "Documents" folder to his VS Project.

Comment: @Till: You may in-fact be correct. In that case, it should be a simple `Path.Combine` from the assembly directory and "Documents".

Comment: I’m the one at fault here…since I shouldn’t have named my document “Documents” which causes the confusion with the built-in windows folder “My Documents”.

Btw, this info you gave me is still great since I was unaware of being able to access “special” folders like that…so I guess it was worth posting here no matter what :-)

Comment: @Zypto: Try the second half (using `Path.Combine`) and see if that works for you. Also, since you are debugging you'll always (unless output path is changed) end up in `bin\debug`. If you make an installer, it will point to the installed location as well (but keep in mind you may need to bypass UAC, and need a manifest file).

Comment: Thanks Brad! I’m almost there!
It turns out the string brings me to the following “C:\MyProject\bin\Debug\Documents”
Unfortunately, the “Documents” folder does not exist there. How can I make my newly created folder “Documents” appear inside the bin\Debug\
Must be a setting I’m overlooking…

Comment: Ohhh…ok ok I get it now!
I had to change the “Copy to Output Directory” for each PDF file inside my “Documents” folder so that when I build the project, that folder appears there!
Great :-) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @zypto: glad to have helped. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to tell Visual Studio to copy the files to output or, as i would probably do it, have them reside in %APPDATA%

Comment: Yes that is correct, I just found out about the Copy to Output Directory :-)